# Too many open files error, but only when accessing through a mounted disk

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel, open-files

I am having a problem where once I try to copy something from a mounted unit on a windows dfs server (Windows server 2012), I get the "Too many open files" errors from linux, but ONLY if I try to copy something from that mounted unit.

The linux server is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago), the mount was done using mount from util-linux-ng 2.17.2 (with libblkid and selinux support).

I also upped the ulimit of open files and processes from our server to a huge amount (2000000) and when the error happens, `lsof` and the `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr` file were around 30000 files opened, yet I still receive the message if I try to access this disk.

The error happens suddenly and I haven't been able to reproduce it, but once it does, I could check that I was able to copy and move files freely from linux, but couldnt copy something from the dfs server to linux.

I will appreciate any kind of assistance, i've tried looking all over the logs place and I haven't been able to found a single reference to "too many open files" in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself:

The reason seems to be that processes fired up by `init` do not inherit the same permissions as the ones from users, the issue was coming from either samba or nfs services ( we are using CIFS, could be related ), I changed both of these service ulimits in `/etc/sysconfig/nfs/` and `/etc/sysconfig/samba` and we haven't got the problem since.